# surf() to bar3() "Matrix dimensions must agree, not rendering mesh"

Tags: matlab, matrix, dimensions

This is my attempt to simulate the water surface. It works fine when I use the `surf()` function. But when I change it to `bar3()`, this error occurs: "Matrix dimensions must agree, not rendering mesh". Can some one please tell me how to fix this? Here's my code:

```
      n=60;
      i = 2:n-1;
      j = 2:n-1;
      H = ones(n,n);

      Dropx=30; %x and y coordinate of the droplet
      Dropy=30;
      width=20;
      r=width/2;
      dt=0.1;
      dx=0.3;

      %%% add droplet to the surface %%%
      [x,y] = ndgrid(-1.5:(2/(width/1.5-1)):1);
      D = 8*exp(-5*(x.^2+y.^2));
      w = size(D,1);
      i2 = (Dropx-r):w+(Dropx-r)-1;
      j2 = (Dropy-r):w+(Dropy-r)-1;
      H(i2,j2) = H(i2,j2) + D;

      oldH=H;
      newH=H;
      h=surf(newH); % cannot change this to bar3
      axis([1 n 1 n -2 8]);
      k=0.2; %damping constant
      c=2;   %wave speed

      while 1==1
          newH(i,j)=H(i,j)+(1-k*dt)*(H(i,j)-oldH(i,j))-...
          dt^2*c^2/dx^2*((4*H(i,j)-H(i+1,j)-H(i-1,j)-H(i,j+1)-H(i,j-1))...
          +0.4*(4*H(i,j)-H(i+1,j+1)-H(i+1,j-1)-H(i-1,j+1)-H(i-1,j-1)));
          set(h,'Zdata', newH(i,j));
          oldH=H;
          H=newH;
          pause(0.05);
      end
```

Comment: I can't resolve this, but the problem is that `h=mesh(H)` creates a single handle `h`, to a `Surfaceplot` object, which is the mesh plot. On the other hand, `bar3` creates a series of patch graphics objects, each with their own handle. So `h=bar3(H)` creates a vector of handles to patch graphics objects. Each handle corresponds to each column of the matrix `H`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, as stated by David, is that `bar3` transforms the original data matrix into a special `ZData`. This new one is a cell array of patches, of length `n` (60 in your code), each of them is an array of size `[n*6,4]`. So you cannot assign directly your new matrix to `ZData`.

There is one solution, besides recreating the plot each time. Basically, it modifies directly `ZData`. You can directly modify element by element `Zdata`. For that, try the following code instead of calling `set(h,'Zdata', newH(i,j));`:

```
for ih=j
    set(h(ih), 'ZData', kron(newH(i,ih),[nan 0 0 nan;0,1,1,0;0,1,1,0;nan 0 0 nan;nan 0 0 nan;nan nan nan nan]));
end
```

`h` is the handle of the plot; in the case of `bar3`, its length is `n`, the first dimension of your matrix. So, for each bar column, you set the `ZData` according to its format. Each element V of the matrix is transformed to this matrix:

```
NaN 0   0   NaN
0   V   V   0
0   V   V   0
NaN 0   0   NaN
NaN 0   0   NaN
NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

So, in order to build the complete `ZData` of each column, you call the function `kron` with the column of the updated matrix and with this atomic matrix.

This is not very fast; on my computer, the display lags time to time, but it is faster than recreating the bar plot each time. Using `surf` is more faster because there is less patches to draw.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I've been looking for. Too bad I don't have enough repution to vote up your answer. So just Thank You!

Comment: @user3611143 I think you should be able to accept the answer even with low reputation. And you can upvote later when you'll have more reputation ;) Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the way you handle the plotting.

```
h=bar3(newH);
```

plots the data and stores handles to patch graphic objects in h. When you write the following :

```
set(h,'Zdata', newH(i,j));
```

you assume that the handle 'Zdata' is a 60x60 array, which is not the case for bar3. Just write

```
output = get(h,'Zdata')
```

to see that. It requires a bit more data handling to do it this way but that seems tedious.

I propose an easy solution to this, simply replotting at every timestep :

```
oldH=H;
newH=H;
h=bar3(newH);
axis([1 n 1 n -2 8]);
k=0.2; %damping constant
c=2;   %wave speed

while 1==1
    newH(i,j)=H(i,j)+(1-k*dt)*(H(i,j)-oldH(i,j))-...
    dt^2*c^2/dx^2*((4*H(i,j)-H(i+1,j)-H(i-1,j)-H(i,j+1)-H(i,j-1))...
    +0.4*(4*H(i,j)-H(i+1,j+1)-H(i+1,j-1)-H(i-1,j+1)-H(i-1,j-1))); 
    h=bar3(newH);
    axis([1 n 1 n -2 8]);
    oldH=H;
    H=newH;
    pause(0.05);
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Replotting at every timestep resolves the problem.